# Getting empty array on applying splice. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, replace, splice

Here I want to add word at the last 4 letter before the x length. So i converted the string to array. Applied split. But when i tried to splice. Getting empty string on adding the second argument to the splice. Looking for help.

```js
let x = "abcdefgh";
console.log(x);
console.log(x.length);
let y = x.split('');
console.log(y);
let len = (y.length - 4);
console.log(len);
console.log(y.splice(len));
console.log(y.splice(len, 0, "test"));
```

Comment: what is your expected output? you have way to many console.logs in there

Comment: Please read what [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does.

Comment: @PhilippSander Expected out is [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'test', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' ]

Please run the above code. You will come to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is understanding what `Array#splice()` returns

Per [Array#splice() MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> Returns: An array containing the deleted elements. If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned. If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

---

So do the splice first then log the whole array to see results

```js
let x = "abcdefgh";

let y = x.split('');

let len = (y.length - 4);
y.splice(len, 0, "test");

console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to insert from characters from the left

```
console.log([x.slice(0,4), wordtoBeinserted, x.slice(4)].join(''));
```

The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.